# How to verify a signed JWT with SubtleCrypto of the Web Crypto API?

Tags: javascript, jwt, webcrypto-api

I'm trying to verify the signature of a JWT using the SubtleCrypto interface of the Web Crypto API.

My code will not verify the token signature while the debug tool at JWT.io will and I don't know why. Here is my verify function:

```
function verify (jwToken, jwKey) {
  const partialToken = jwToken.split('.').slice(0, 2).join('.')
  const signaturePart = jwToken.split('.')[2]
  const encoder = new TextEncoder()
  return window.crypto.subtle
    .importKey('jwk', jwKey, { 
         name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5', 
         hash: { name: 'SHA-256' } 
       }, false, ['verify'])
    .then(publicKey =>
      window.crypto.subtle.verify(
        { name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5' },
        publicKey,
        encoder.encode(atob(signaturePart)),
        encoder.encode(partialToken)
      ).then(isValid => alert(isValid ? 'Valid token' : 'Invalid token'))
    )
}
```

I expected that code to work and provide a positive verification of a properly signed JWT. Instead the example code fail to verify the signed token. The example fail in Chrome 71 for me.

I have also set up some [tests](https://dahnielson.github.io/rfc7520/) using the example data from RFC 7520.

Comment: `signaturePart` and `partialToken` are base64url encoded. You need to decode them before using `verify`

Comment: @pedrofb You are right that the `signaturePart` need to be decoded. However `partialToken` (the JWS Signature Input) should not be decoded for the verification step per section 5. in RFC 7515.

Comment: My mistake. No need to decode `partialToken`. The signature is base64url encoded which is slighly different to base64. Before applying `atob` you need to replace `+` with `-` and `/` with `_`

Comment: Yep, that and using `btoa()` is really bad as it can't handle non-alphabet characters in the output, so the 'b' for binary in the functions name isn't really true. I switched to using rfc4648.js and it works perfectly. :)

Comment: You may want to answer your own question with the solution for future use

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To verify a JWS with SubtleCrypto you need to be careful to encode and decode the data properly between binary and base64url representation. Unfortunately the [standard implementation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-atob) in the browser of `btoa()` and `atob()` are difficult to work with as they use "a Unicode string containing only characters in the range U+0000 to U+00FF, each representing a binary byte with values 0x00 to 0xFF respectively" as the representation of binary data.

A better solution to represent binary data in Javascript is to use ES6 object [`TypedArray`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-typedarray-objects) and use a Javascript library (or write the encoder yourself) to convert them to base64url that honors [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648).

> Side note: The difference between base64 and base64url is the characters selected for value 62 and 63 in the standard, base64 encode them to `+` and `/` while base64url encode `-` and `_`.

An example of such a library in Javascript is [rfc4648.js](https://github.com/swansontec/rfc4648.js).

```
import { base64url } from 'rfc4648'

async function verify (jwsObject, jwKey) {
  const jwsSigningInput = jwsObject.split('.').slice(0, 2).join('.')
  const jwsSignature = jwsObject.split('.')[2]
  return window.crypto.subtle
    .importKey('jwk', jwKey, { 
         name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5', 
         hash: { name: 'SHA-256' } 
       }, false, ['verify'])
    .then(key=>
      window.crypto.subtle.verify(
        { name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5' },
        key,
        base64url.parse(jwsSignature, { loose: true }),
        new TextEncoder().encode(jwsSigningInput))
      ).then(isValid => alert(isValid ? 'Valid token' : 'Invalid token'))
    )
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot !