# How to verify an ES256 JWT token using Web Crypto when public key is distributed in PEM?

Tags: web, cryptography, jwt

I need to verify ES256 JWT tokens in a Cloudflare Worker. To my understanding they do not run Node.js there and I will have to make everything work with the Web Crypto API (available in browsers, too, as `window.crypto.subtle`). However, I am expecting to receive the public keys as PEM files and I think I am having problems importing them.

I have been trying to modify an existing open source JWT implementation that only supports HS256 to support ES256.

In addition to trying to use the actual tokens and keys, and keys generated in browsers and OpenSSL, I have tried to use a working example from the JWT.io website (after converting it to JWK format using node-jose), since it should validate correctly. But I am not getting any errors, my code running in browser just tells me the token is not valid.

Here is my Node REPL session I used for converting the key from JWT.io to JWK:

```js
> const jose = require('node-jose')
> const publicKey = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
... MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEEVs/o5+uQbTjL3chynL4wXgUg2R9
... q9UU8I5mEovUf86QZ7kOBIjJwqnzD1omageEHWwHdBO6B+dFabmdT9POxg==
... -----END PUBLIC KEY-----`
> const keyStore = jose.JWK.createKeyStore()
> keyStore.add(publicKey, 'pem')
> keyStore.toJSON()
{
  keys: [
    {
      kty: 'EC',
      kid: '19J8y7Zprt2-QKLjF2I5pVk0OELX6cY2AfaAv1LC_w8',
      crv: 'P-256',
      x: 'EVs_o5-uQbTjL3chynL4wXgUg2R9q9UU8I5mEovUf84',
      y: 'kGe5DgSIycKp8w9aJmoHhB1sB3QTugfnRWm5nU_TzsY'
    }
  ]
}
>
```

Here is the failing validation, based on code from `webcrypto-jwt` package:

```js
function utf8ToUint8Array(str) {
    // Adapted from https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/LayoutTests/crypto/subtle/hmac/sign-verify.html
    var Base64URL = {
        stringify: function (a) {
        var base64string = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(0, a));
        return base64string.replace(/=/g, '').replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
        },
        parse: function (s) {
        s = s.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/\s/g, '');
        return new Uint8Array(Array.prototype.map.call(atob(s), function (c) { return c.charCodeAt(0); }));
        }
    };
    str = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)));
    return Base64URL.parse(str);
}

var cryptoSubtle = (crypto && crypto.subtle) ||
(crypto && crypto.webkitSubtle) ||
(window.msCrypto && window.msCrypto.Subtle);

// Token from JWT.io
var tokenParts = [
    'eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9', 
    'eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTUxNjIzOTAyMn0',
    'tyh-VfuzIxCyGYDlkBA7DfyjrqmSHu6pQ2hoZuFqUSLPNY2N0mpHb3nk5K17HWP_3cYHBw7AhHale5wky6-sVA'
];

// Public key from JWT.io converted in Node using node-jose
var publicKey = {
    kty: 'EC',
    kid: '19J8y7Zprt2-QKLjF2I5pVk0OELX6cY2AfaAv1LC_w8',
    crv: 'P-256',
    x: 'EVs_o5-uQbTjL3chynL4wXgUg2R9q9UU8I5mEovUf84',
    y: 'kGe5DgSIycKp8w9aJmoHhB1sB3QTugfnRWm5nU_TzsY'
};

var importAlgorithm = {
    name: 'ECDSA',
    namedCurve: 'P-256',
    hash: 'SHA-256',
};

cryptoSubtle.importKey(
    "jwk",
    publicKey,
    importAlgorithm,
    false,
    ["verify"]
).then(function (key) {
    var partialToken = tokenParts.slice(0,2).join('.');
    var signaturePart = tokenParts[2];

    cryptoSubtle.verify(
        importAlgorithm,
        key,
        utf8ToUint8Array(signaturePart),
        utf8ToUint8Array(partialToken)
    ).then(function (ok) {
        if (ok) {
            console.log("I think it's valid");
        } else {
            console.log("I think it isn't valid");
        }
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log("error verifying", err);
    });
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log("error importing", err);
});
```

Since I copied a valid key and a valid token from JWT.io, I am expecting the code to log "I think it's valid" without errors. It does not show any errors, indeed, but it ends up in "I think it isn't valid" branch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to verify a signed JWT with SubtleCrypto of the Web Crypto API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54062583/how-to-verify-a-signed-jwt-with-subtlecrypto-of-the-web-crypto-api)

Answer (score 1):

Answered here [How to verify a signed JWT with SubtleCrypto of the Web Crypto API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54062583/how-to-verify-a-signed-jwt-with-subtlecrypto-of-the-web-crypto-api)

So, if I understood correctly, the problem was that base64 encoding included in the open source upstream just does not work correctly in one of the directions, since it uses the browser's btoa. Adapting https://github.com/swansontec/rfc4648.js instead works.